# Function tied to ng-click which applies style change to div element only fires properly after page has been refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am using AngularJs and jQuery.  I have a div element on my page which encompasses other div elements that represent tabs for school subjects.  Only four subjects are to be displayed at a time.  There are arrows to either side of this parent div which when pressed will change the style of the parent div so that its left property will shift 100% in the appropriate direction.  This shift reveals the next 4 (or fewer) subjects.  The arrows have the ng-click directive as an attribute which is tied to a function that uses the .css() jQuery method to accomplish this style change.  The issue I'm having is that the function won't fire initially.  However, if I refresh the page all functionality works just fine.  What could be happening after the refresh which would allow everything to work properly?

Comment: [Don't use jQuery with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).  But if you do, wrap jQuery code with `$timeout` because it is not part of AngularJS digest cycle. You can call it manually with `$scope.$apply()` too, add that into your function that you call with `ng-click` to re-render the page and apply your changes. DOM manipulations are for _directives_, which use jQLite

Comment: This makes sense.  Thank you!